# Automatically installing Ubuntu with preseed file on VM

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I would like to install Ubuntu for my virtual machine unattendedly and won't wanna make a customized ISO as follows:

- Create a .flp file;
- in an existed Ubuntu, run grub-mkrescue to build a floppy image with preseed file (preseed.cfg) and a kickstart file (ks.cfg);
- configure the grub.cfg to enable booting from cdrom with the installation configuration files attached

i.e.,

```
insmod ata
set root=(ata0)
linux /casper/vmlinuz ks=floppy:/ks.cfg file=floppy:/pressed.cfg boot=casper only-ubiquity
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
boot
```

Then create a VM with cdrom and floppy inserted (e.g. ubuntu10.04.iso, grub-ubuntu.flp) and start the VM.

However, the configuration window for installation is always shown to ask for doing actions like selecting language, partitioning disk. Thus the boot program apparently cannot find the kickstart file.

I also tried `ks=floppy, ks=/floppy/ks.cfg, ks=/dev/floppy/0/ks.cfg, ks=hd:fd0:/ks.cfg, ks=fd0:/ks.cfg, ks=/dev/fd0/ks.cfg`, none of them works. The same for preseed/file option.

How can I make the kernel load floppy and the kickstart file to install Ubuntu automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the directions [on this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu) and it worked great.

Here's an example of the kernel boot instructions as found on that page:

> append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --